# Set parameterized responseCode.code check on Collection level

Tags: javascript, postman

A bit tired of changing response tests statusCode after endpoint changing.

Want to set Collection level responseCode.code test for only two status codes - 200 and 204 acceptable.

Now on Collection level I wrote this one:

```
if (responseCode.code === 204) {
    console.log("204");
} else {
    if (responseCode.code !== 200){
        pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    });
        let responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseBody);
        console.log(responseJSON); 
        return;
    }
}
```

it checks the status correctly but throws it as code error if wrong (ex. 500 Server Error returned), not as failed expect. Accordingly, in TeamCity CI it's not highlighted as a failed test

Does someone use something similar for your collection with using:

```
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
```

or

```
responseCode.code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use this:

```
pm.test("Check response code", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200, 204])
})
```

Quite basic and might not be what you need but it will fail if the response code returned is not either 200 or 204.

Comment: Uhhh, why is this so simple :) Thanks, man. it's helped. Only one thing that a bit uncleared here that you use pm.expect instead of just expect instead of pm.test, never used this option, need to read about it.

Comment: That's no problem, wasn't sure if this would be all you need though. It's quite a basic check. It's just using the chaijs syntax - https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: Yeah, as I said I know it, just did not contrive to use this simple. One thing a bit is not clear for me that u used pm.expect instead of just expect that postman propose, and behaviour is different in both options. But anyway that everything that i needed - accept only 2 options of response code in one place for the whole collection

Comment: Postman uses `pm.expect()` to reference the chai library. If you used just `expect` within a test, it would probably fail. I think the old PostmanBDD module used just expect but it seems pointless using that now.